# Codeigniter 404 Error not working properly

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

i am trying to make a website on Codeigniter for the first time.
and i have a problem with 404 error, 
when i type

```
Domainname.com/anything
```

it should give me a 404 error, or at least a page with 404 error status code,
but no it's getting me to the home page with status code 200

Comment: paste your route files content here.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new controller and view for 404 page. Then in your routes.php add the following line of code:

```
$route['404_override'] = 'ErrorPage';
```

ErrorPage is the class name

```
class ErrorPage extends CI_Controller {

public function index() { 
    $this->load->view('404page.php'); 
} }
```